# Output file isn't encoded in UTF-8 when using a standalone Talend job

Tags: utf-8, talend

I have a simple Talend job that reads a CSV file as entry, sends a SOAP request to a webservice and then returns some fields of the response in a CSV file as output. The job deals with adresses throughout Europe, so the various fields of the output can have accents or non-latin characters (e.g. for adresses in Belarus) in them.

When I run the job inside Talend Open Studio, my output file is correctly encoded in UTF-8 and all the special characters appear fine when I open the file in Notepad++. However, when I export the job as a standalone (using the "Build Job" menu option) and run the .bat file, none of the special characters are correctly encoded. When I open the file in Notepad++ it clearly says that it's encoded in UTF-8, but the end result is still wrong.

Am I missing something, or doing something wrong? I haven't found any option in Talend besides choosing "UTF-8" as encoding in the advanced options of my tFileOutputDelimited component.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` as an argument to your JVM should solve the issue.
In order to set this in Talend, you can use the advanced settings tab in the Run view, and add a JVM argument: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

You can set this globally in Talend preferences as well: Windows > Preferences > Talend > Run/Debug

Comment: I'm getting a "Could not find or load main class Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" error when trying that. I'm using Amazon Corretto 8 Open JDK, could it be related to either this or my initial problem?

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, forgot the "-" before the argument, could you try with "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"